# how to define the Console.WriteLine behavior for a class in C#?

Tags: c#, string, tostring

I have a class:

```
class Rect{
    int x;
    int y;
    public Rect(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

I want this happen:

```
Console.WriteLine(new Rect(12,12));
>>> <Rect with x=12, y=12>
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override `ToString()` method:

```
class Rect{
    int x;
    int y;
    public Rect(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "("+x.ToString()+","+y.ToString()+")";
    }

}
```

Comment: C# is not Java. `ToString` is PascalCase.

Comment: In the same thinking, `Rect` is not a valid name either.

Comment: Also, calling `.ToString()` on the int variables explicitly is not required here.  C# compiler will automatically insert that call when it sees the addition operator with an string operand ("string" + object)

Answer (score 1):

[Console.WriteLine Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx)

You need to override the `ToString()` method from `Object`.